# selecting a range of verses from a database

Tags: sql, ms-access, vbscript, asp-classic

i have a database, with verses from the bible, with those fields:
book (book number), chapter (chapter number), verse (verse number), text (the verse)

*example: 1 1 1 In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.*
first 1 is for **Genesis**, second 1 is for **chapter 1**, third 1 is for **verse 1**

user gives me something like 1 1:1 - 1 1:4 which means he wants to show Genesis 1:1-4.

what i want to do is something like
 `SELECT (book*1000000+chapter*1000+verse AS index) FROM bible WHERE index >= 1001001 AND index <=1001004`
 or
 `WHERE book*1000000+chapter*1000+verse >= 1001001 AND book*1000000+chapter*1000+verse <= 1001004`

Comment: You might want to consider going to millions for the book, to reserve 3 digits for Psalms that has over 100 chapters.

Comment: What's your question? Is there something not working with your sql above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the single column "index", but instead of calculating it each time for the query (which performs 1000 times slower), do a one off population from the formula "book*1000000+chapter*1000+verse".

```
UPDATE bible
SET index = book * 1000000 + chapter * 1000 + verse
```

Let's say you have controls in the form to choose book, chapter and verse, both for start and end.  You would then build the filters as

```
SELECT index, verse
FROM bible
WHERE index >=
    Forms!f!startBook * 1000000 + Forms!f!startChapter + 1000 + Forms!f!startVerse
AND index <=
    Forms!f!endBook * 1000000 + Forms!f!endChapter + 1000 + Forms!f!Verse
```

If you must use the calculated column each time (I have more than an inkling that it is more than 1ms), then

```
SELECT index_, verse
FROM (select book * 1000000 + chapter * 1000 + verse as index_, * from bible) B
WHERE index_ >= 1 AND index_ <= 2
```

Where the two ?'s are ASP command placeholders for parameters.  Precalculate the index using the same formula

```
startIndex = Request("sbook") * 1000000 + Request("schapter") * 1000 + Request("sverse")
```

Comment: i am using it with ASP/VBscript i want to keep my database the smallest.. therefore i prefer adding 1ms for the page to load else than having redundant data on my database. thank you

Answer (score 0):

this works: 
SELECT text FROM bible WHERE book*1000000+chapter*1000+verse >=" & from & "AND book*1000000+chapter*1000+verse <=" & last